# How to find all the data rows with column1 values more than twice the average column1 value across the dataset?

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery, average, aggregate-functions

I am trying find all the data rows with column1 values more than twice the average column1 value across the dataset with the code below but it seems it's not correct data.
Here is the code:

```
select *,column1 over() from databasetest.Table1
where column1 > (select 2*avg(column1) from databasetest.Table1)
```

And here is the sample output

[image]

As you can see, the column1 value is still less than the twice the average column1 value across the dataset. I thought this should retrieve columns with more than twice the average column1 value across the dataset.
Did I do something wrong or I misunderstand something?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (select t1.*, avg(column1) over () as avg_column1
      from databasetest.Table1 t1
     ) t1
where t1.column1 > 2 * avg_column1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time, Do you know why my code does not work?

Comment: @lili . . . Your code is syntactically incorrect.